# GeoDesic Buffers sample code does not work in my local IIS Server

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, geodesic-sphere

I am new to use ArcGis Api for javascript, I am using JS Api 3.20.
   I have been trying for 3 days but it does not work.
   I have taken code from the following link
   Geometry Engine - Geodesic buffers | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.20 
   I paste this in My Html file create in VS website for .Net , and setup a local server for my page using IIS server
   I also downloaded proxy from GitHub resource-proxy/DotNet at master · Esri/resource-proxy · GitHub 
   setup it in same application in IIS
   Downloaded excel file added in my application    from https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.csv 
   but still I am getting the following error in console using developer mode when set Proxy URL to this
    config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/192.168.8.188/Proxy/proxy.ashx";

```
GET http://192.168.8.188:1555/192.168.8.188/Proxy/proxy.ashx?http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.csv 404 (Not Found)
```

and when I set proxy url to this 
 config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/Proxy/";
then the following error occurs in console

```
GET http://192.168.8.188:1555/Proxy/?http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.csv 403 (Forbidden)
```

Could you please help me out. I would be thankful in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I Resolved My Issue thanks.

Basically I didn't enable IIS 4.5 web features so I read readme file of proxy which resolved my issue.

Here is what I read from ReadMe file located in DotNet folder of Proxy

- Troubleshooting: If you get an error message 404.3, it's possible that ASP.NET have not been set up. On Windows 8, go to "Turn Windows features on or off" -> "Internet Information Services" -> "World Wide Web Services" -> "Application Development Features" -> "ASP.NET 4.5".

Answer (score 0):

First off, try setting the proxyUrl value to this:

```
config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/proxy.ashx";
```

That may resolve the issue.

EDIT (based on clarification that IIS is in fact running on port 1555):

You might want to confirm that you can access the proxy at all, by entering the proxy url directly in your browser (with no arguments), eg:

http://192.168.8.188:1555/Proxy/proxy.ashx

If this resolves correctly, you should get an error response in JSON format like this:

> {error: {code: 400,message:"This proxy does not support empty
>   parameters."}}

That at least would confirm that the proxy is accessible and functioning properly on your system.

Comment: I use 1555 port because 80 is used by another process, and in both cases  (80 , 1555) I get not found error when requesting 
http://192.168.8.188:1555/Proxy/proxy.ashx

Or 

http://192.168.8.188/Proxy/proxy.ashx

Comment: #Dave Marley When I set Proxy to this one I get not found error
config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/proxy.ashx";

Comment: OK makes sense regarding the port. Thx for clarifying. If http://192.168.8.188:1555/Proxy/proxy.ashx doesn't resolve even when entering directly in browser then something must be wrong with your IIS settings for the proxy page/application. Can you open IIS manager, right click on Proxy.ashx and select browse? Does that result in the JSON error showing in your browser as noted in my response?

Comment: I don't have proxy.ashx in IIS as such because I converted DotNet folder to application named it proxy, while proxy.ashx is located in DotNet folder